# A Dirty Little War

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

In CHAT we've been discussing the ongoing Russo-Ukrainian conflict: a dirty little war which should never have happened.

How to express this, in Latin?

> "bellum turpissimum numquam quod factum esset."

This, involving a neuter relative clause with the pluperfect passive subjunctive of "fio" = "to happen".

Is this translation correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- I think ***turpis*** is a good choice to mean "repulsive, dirty, shameful". To further express the "little" part one could use its diminutive - ***turpiculus*** - but this adds the connotation of indifference and pettiness which may not be quite your intention. There are many near-synonyms like ***flāgitiōsus*** "shameful, outrageous", ***dēfōrmis*** "ugly, repulsive", ***sordidus*** "dirty, base".

  - Another way to approach translating this is to observe that "dirty little" isn't a literal expression with a clearly defined meaning, but rather a fixed idiomatic epithet expressing general disgust and condemnation. A Latin equivalent immediately presents itself: ***nēquam.*** Indeed, this (and the adverb *nēquiter*) is found in conjunction with *turpis (turpiter)* at least twice.
- "Which should never have happened" is used in English to express a value judgement "I think it could have been avoided" or "I wish it wouldn't have happened". To express the wish in Latin you need to add ***utinam*** to your translation. To express the possibility of being avoided you'd say *quod (sānē, facile etc.) vītārī poterat.*

  - *bellum fierī nōn oportēbat* has a different interpretation, namely "there was no intention or obligation for the war to happen."

To summarise, one way to translate your sentence would be:

- *bellum turpe (nēquam, etc.) [quod utinam numquam ēvēnisset](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/1212/1/64/173-184#64),* or
- *flāgitiōsum [est] illud bellum, atque sānē vītārī poterat.*

Answer (score 3):

*Turpe* is fine, but *turpissimum* is too strong for "dirty little war." *Bellum turpissimum* feels like something you'd describe an outright massacre or prolonged engagement. Of course, I'm not sure "dirty little war" is strong enough to describe the Ukraine invasion, but perhaps this is a difference between American bluntness and English irony.

Besides *turpe*, specifically for the phrase "dirty little war," I'd also offer *impudens* as a choice. I'd phrase it all with the following:

> Impudens est hoc bellum, quod numquam oporteat.

Compare it to Cicero:

> est enim aliquid, quod non oporteat, etiam si licet: quicquid vero non licet, certe non oportet (Cic. Balb. 3.7)

I'd personally make it present tense (as I did) instead of perfect (but not pluperfect), since the war is still ongoing. I clarified as much with the *est* in the first clause.

Comment: Thank you. An excellent answer, as always. Here, "little" isn't so much a comment on the magnitude of the conflict, but it's legitimacy. Further, by implication, the "little men" who start wars whose primary motivations tend to be money, land & power. Thanks again.

Comment: *impudēns* means "cheeky, shameless", describing a mental attitude of throwing a challenge. Besides animate beings it can only refer to acts or attitudes by metonymy. *—quod nōn oportet* means "something one shouldn't do" (a generalising moral maxim). You need to supply a verb meaning "happen" and change the tense: *quod nōn oportēbat fierī.* But even this refers to an external obligation or necessity, while the English expression means "it could have been prevented".

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian In Cicero, *quod no oporteat* is definitely not a "generalizing moral maxim." It's a very specific moral prohibition: "It is our duty to not do that whether it's legal or not, and it's not legal, so we definitely shouldn't do it!" Calling it a "generalizing moral maxim" is not doing Cicero or the phrase justice.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian I already said at the beginning that *turpis* is an excellent choice, but do note that "dirty little" already has the connotations of "cheekiness" in it. The diminutive negates the severity that *turpis* suggests. And it's not a light-hearted cheekiness, but one of fraud. For this reason Cicero twice uses it in the *In Verrem*, both times indicating Verres' (and his cohort's) swindling.

Comment: Would I use it to describe the actual conflict? No. But I would use it for what he wanted translated.

Comment: @tony That part should be in the OP. I read "dirty little" in the sense of "our dirty little secret." To my ears, "dirty little war" would describe clandestine operations, not a 40 mile column of Russian soldiers and tanks!

Comment: *impudēns* cannot translate "dirty" at all, it means "challenging the norms of modesty and propriety, arrogant, disrepsectful, cheeky". *impudīcus* can translate "dirty" in the sense "inappropriately sexually arousing", but not in the sense required. You might be trying to find a Latin equivalent for "causing a feeling of shame", for example *pudendus* - but this one's about personal morals and other intimate things.

Comment: As for *oporteat,* I think you misunderstand. I call it a generic moral maxim in the same sense as there's a generic "you": *est enim aliquid, quod non oporteat, etiam si licet* means "there are things that you (one) shouldn't do even if it's allowed." This is the generalising meaning of the present tense *quod oportet* "what should be done" just like in *quod licet (Jovī)* "what is allowed." Your use of it in *quod numquam oporteat* is incorrect, it cannot express the objective "that shouldn't happen" because it means "something one shouldn't do" . This is why I called it a moral maxim.

Comment: Moreover *bellum quod nōn oportet* is ungrammatical because *(id) quod (nōn) oportet* cannot be an adjectival clause but only a substantival one. It means "what should be done", not "of a kind that should be done". *quod nōn oportet/licet* can also be used parenthetically to qualify an entire clause, which is when it can be translated as "something, which": *dulcia mea sūmpsit, quod nōn licet* "she took my sweets, which isn't allowed...". But with *oportet* it would mean "which isn't required, isn't the plan of action". In a restrictive adjectival subjuncitve clause it makes no sense.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian We will have to agree to disagree on *impudens*. But do note that "dirty" is far more versatile in English that you give it credit. (E.g., dirty rotten scoundrel.). I do need to re-look at *oprtet*, but I wasn't making it a personal verb.

Comment: Its versatility in English is not in question. We aren't trying to establish the meaning of "dirty" in tony's original, we already know that it isn't "challenging the norms of modesty and propriety, arrogant, disrepsectful, cheeky". The latter is the only thing *impudēns* can express - that the war is arrogant and disrespectful. This is a question of fact which is confirmed by consulting a dictionary. I'm sorry but I don't believe in saying "let's agree to disagree" to avoid admitting that facts aren't on one's side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134714/discussion-between-cmw-and-unbrutal-russian).